# How to fdopen as open with the same mode and flags?

Tags: c, file-io, printf, fdopen

I would like to have a `FILE*` type to use `fprintf`.
I need to use `fdopen` to get a `FILE*` instead of `open` that returns an `int`.
But can we do the same with `fdopen` and `open`? (I never used `fdopen`)

I would like to do a `fdopen` that does the same as :

```
open("my_file", 0_CREAT | O_RDWR | O_TRUNC, 0644);
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`fdopen` takes a file descriptor that could be previously returned by `open`, so that is not a problem.

Just `open` your file getting the descriptor, and then `fdopen` that descriptor.

`fdopen` simply creates a userspace-buffered stream, taking any kind of descriptor that supports the `read` and `write` operations.

Comment: Don't forget to that the modes to `fdopen` must be compatible with the file descriptor ones.

Answer (score 9):

### `fdopen()`use file descriptor to file pointer:

The [`fdopen()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604499/functions/fdopen.html) function associates a stream with a file descriptor. File descriptors are obtained from `open()`, `dup()`, `creat()`, or `pipe()`, which open files but do not return pointers to a `FILE` structure stream. Streams are necessary input for almost all of the stdio library routines.

```
FILE* fp = fdopen(fd, "w");
```

this example code may help you more as you want to use `fprintf()`:

```
int main(){
 int fd;
 FILE *fp;
 fd = open("my_file",O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC);
  if(fd<0){
    printf("open call fail");
    return -1;
 }
 fp=fdopen(fd,"w");
 fprintf(fp,"we got file pointer fp bu using File descriptor fd");
 fclose(fp);
 return 0;
}
```

**Notice:**

- The mode of the stream must be compatible with the mode of the file descriptor.
- When the stream is closed via `fclose()`, fd is closed also.
  ref: [The `fclose()` function performs a `close()` on the file descriptor that is associated with the stream pointed to by stream.](http://www.mkssoftware.com/docs/man3/fclose.3.asp)

Comment: You should *not* close the file descriptor after having used `fdopen` on it and then `fclose`. The `fd` is *not* dup'ed and calling `fclose` will close it.

Comment: Quoting man page: `The file  descriptor is not dup'ed, and will be closed when the stream created by fdopen() is closed.` Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8417123/mixing-fdopen-and-open-bad-file-descriptor

Comment: That doesn't write anything in the file.

Comment: @Elfayer It should work, Try again also here is one more [example](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Frtref%2Ffdopen.htm)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have previously acquired a file-descriptor for your file, rather use `fopen`.

```
FILE* file = fopen("pathtoyourfile", "w+");
```

Consider, that `fopen` is using the stand-library-calls and not the system-calls (open). So you don't have that many options (like specifying the access-control-values).

See the [man-page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fdopen).